# Summation over a second order polynomial

Tags: polynomials

in my Solid State Physics class my professor wrote:

$$U=\frac{c}{2}\sum_{n}\left(u_{n+1}-u_n\right)^2\tag{1}$$

$$=\frac{c}{2}\sum_{n}\left(u_{n+1}^2+u_n^2-2u_{n+1}u_n\right)\tag{2}$$

$$=\frac{c}{2}\sum_{n}\left(2u_n^2-u_{n+1}u_n-u_nu_{n-1}\right)\tag{3}$$

How he went from (2) to (3) ?

Comment: He did it by changing for which $n$ you count certain terms. Write out the sum for $n$ up to four or five, and you'll see it.

Answer (score 1):

Note for example that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{10}f(n)=f(1)+\ldots+f(10)=\sum_{n=0}^9f(n+1).$$
Hence one can make an index shift in the summand if one shifts the imdex bounds accordingly. In your case, we have $\sum_n$, i.e., we sum over *all* $n$, not just a finite range. In that case, the index bounds (and their adjustment) are irrelevant. Therefore
$$ \sum_nu_{n+1}^2 = \sum_n u_n^2\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sum_nu_{n+1}u_{n}=\sum_nu_nu_{n-1}$$
and so ultimatey
$$\begin{align}\sum_n(u_{n+1}^2+u_n^2-2u_{n+1}u_n)&= \sum_nu_{n+1}^2+\sum_nu_n^2-\sum_nu_{n+1}u_n-\sum_nu_{n+1}u_n\\
&=\sum_nu_{n}^2+\sum_nu_n^2-\sum_nu_{n+1}u_n-\sum_nu_{n}u_{n-1}\\
&=\sum_n(2u_n^2-u_{n+1}u_n-u_nu_{n-1}).\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks I understand now, but in the last term $\left(-u_nu_{n-1}\right)$ why he didn't just leave it like $\left(-u_nu_{n+1}\right)$. If they are the same, why he changed to $\left(-u_nu_{n-1}\right)$